# React/JSX Arrow function for JSON object with array.

Tags: reactjs, arrow-functions

I have the following JSON object

```
const slides = [
  {
    title: "Hello World",
    bullets: [
      "Allows us to ... write",
      "Allows us to ... writez",
      "Allows us to ... writezz",
    ],
    slideIndex: 0,
  },
  {
    title: "Hello Worldz",
    bullets: [
      "Allows us to ... write",
      "Allows us to ... writez",
      "Allows us to ... writezz",
    ],
    slideIndex: 1,
  },
];
```

Now I want to use the following component `Slide.js`

```
import React from "react";

const Slide = slide => (
  <div>
    <h1> { slide.title } </h1>
    <ul>
      { slide.bullets.map( bullet => <li> { bullet } </li>)}
    </ul>
  </div>
);

export default Slide;
```

Inside my `App.js` to display the content of the slides variable.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Slide from "./components/Slide.js";

const slides = [ ... ];

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Slide slide={slides} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

How can I loop over the bullets array? I already tried slide.bullets[bullet].map(...) but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const slides = [
  {
    title: "Hello World",
    bullets: [
      "Allows us to ... write",
      "Allows us to ... writez",
      "Allows us to ... writezz"
    ],
    slideIndex: 0
  },
  {
    title: "Hello Worldz",
    bullets: [
      "Allows us to ... write",
      "Allows us to ... writez",
      "Allows us to ... writezz"
    ],
    slideIndex: 1
  }
];

const Slide = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{props.slide.title}</h1>
      <ul>{props.slide.bullets.map(bullet => <li> {bullet} </li>)}</ul>
    </div>
  );
};

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">{slides.map(slide => <Slide slide={slide} />)}</div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your component will receive props. You need to get `slide` from props object.

```
const Slide = (props) => (
    <div>
        <h1> { props.slide.title } </h1>
        <ul>
            { props.slide.bullets.map( bullet => <li> { bullet } </li>)}
        </ul>
    </div>
);
```

or use destructuring,

```
const Slide = ({slide}) => (
  <div>
    <h1> { slide.title } </h1>
    <ul>
      { slide.bullets.map( bullet => <li> { bullet } </li>)}
    </ul>
  </div>
);
```

export default Slide;

Edit:

Also, in your app.js, you have to map over slides array,

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">{slides.map(slide => <Slide slide={slide} />)}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer (gave you plus one). But it seems I also needed to edit my App.js like in the other answer.

Comment: yeah, sorry, i missed that part.

Comment: Appreciate the help!